# How to evaluate a piece of OCaml code dynamically in OCaml program?

Tags: ocaml

For example, I want to load the following files dynamically into my program and print out result.

input1.txt  --> print 100

```
let x = 10 in x * x
```

input2.txt  --> print 3

```
let x = 1 and y = 2 in x + y
```

input3.txt  --> print 4

```
let ls = [1;2;3;4] in List.length ls
```

[ocaml_plugin](https://github.com/janestreet/ocaml_plugin) might be useful to this project. I would like to know more details of how to implement it. Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this?

Comment: I'm building my own runtime graph calculator. A base node is an OCaml expression, for example, `a = let x = 100 in x*x`. A node can be a formula of other nodes, for example `b = a*a`. A base node can take any self-contained OCaml expression. After the input of a base node changes, all nodes depending on it will be re-evaluated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant part in the OCaml reference manual is the chapter on the [dynlink library](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libdynlink.html) (a tutorial can be found [here](http://zderadicka.eu/plugins-in-ocaml-with-dynlink-library/)). `ocaml_plugin` provides a wrapper around this library and compiles your code automatically.

Otherwise, you have to compile your `.ml` files into `.cmo` files before loading them with `dynlink`, either beforehand or calling the compiler from your program (or, being adventurous, directly through the [compiler front-end](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/parsing.html)).

In your examples, there appears to be a common pattern (i.e., a function that takes no arguments and returns an integer) and one may define an interface around this.